# Passing and receiving variables through Process.start parameter (Winform to UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp

My UWP program is registered as protocol and it is made to call through button of Winform program.
I want to receive the value from UWP by passing the variable value in the Winform program, but I'm not sure how to receive the passed argument in UWP(XAML).

> winform

```
 ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

                startinfo.FileName = "safety:";

                startinfo.Arguments = LOGIN.userinfo.user_id;

                Process.Start(startinfo);
```

> UWP(App.Xaml.cs)

```
  protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)

    {
        //Initialize(args);

        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)

        {
           

            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            if (rootFrame == null)

            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page

                rootFrame = new Frame();



                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                

                // Place the frame in the current Window

                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;                    

            }



            // Always navigate for a protocol launch

            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

            // Ensure the current window is active                

            Window.Current.Activate();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass data from the WinForms app to the UWP app when the WinForms app launches the UWP app?  UWP apps won't receive data from the `Process.Start` method.

Comment: omg... thx for answering. i launched uwp app from winform.... Is there any other method?

Comment: What's your real requirement? Do you need the UWP app to receive data from the WinForms app from time to time? Or do you just want the UWP app just receive data only once when the app is launched from the WinForms app?

Comment: Only once. when i click a button in Winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only once. when i click a button in Winform

You could use add the data that you want to app into the [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(Uri, LauncherOptions, ValueSet) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-22000#windows-system-launcher-launchuriasync(windows-foundation-uri-windows-system-launcheroptions-windows-foundation-collections-valueset)). Then you could get the data from the `ProtocolActivatedEventArgs` of the `OnActivated` event.

I have implemented a sample demo based on your code and you could refer to the following code:

UWP app:

```
  protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

            //get the data from Winforms apps
            ValueSet data = eventArgs.Data;
            var d = data["token1"];

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                rootFrame = new Frame();
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

            }
            // pass the data to the MainPage
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), d);            

            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
```

In the MainPage of the UWP app:

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

       var str =  e.Parameter.ToString();

    }
```

When you call the LaunchUriAsync, change it like the following:

```
        // Launch the URI
        var uri = new Uri("alsdk:");
        // create data.
        ValueSet v = new ValueSet();
        v.Add("token1", "12");

        // create LauncherOptions
        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
        options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "PackageFamilyName of Your UWP project";
  
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options, v);
```

Comment: thx for answering. I solved problem!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem another way like this

winform

```
 Process.Start("safetytest:"+LOGIN.userinfo.user_id);
```

UWP(App.Xaml.cs)

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        ThemeHelper.Initialize();

        Initialize(args);
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

            }
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), eventArgs.Uri.ToString());//this
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
```

UWP Main

```
  protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {           
        SafetyApp.user_info.user_id = e.Parameter.ToString().Substring(11);  
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(String.Format(user_info.user_id));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();          
    }
```